# Why doesn't the Profile tab appear for unstructured data when Watson Knowledge Catalog is deployed in London?

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

I have a Watson Knowledge Catalog Lite version that I deployed to the London region. When I click on a PDF file that I have added to my catalog I do not see the "Profile" tab. I have several colleagues that have deployed to Frankfurt and the U.S. and they see the "Profile" tab for unstructured data but I do not.

Answer (score 0):

Certain regions have all the watson services to support unstructured data viewing in the "Profile" tab so this is why it is available and not available based on the region you are at.